# ExecuteAsync() of Azure Table Storage failing to insert all the records

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, azure-table-storage

I am trying to insert 10000 records into Azure table storage. I am using ExecuteAsync() to achieve it, but somehow approximately around 7500 records are inserted and rest of the records are lost. I am purposely not using **await** keyword because I don't want to wait for the result, just want to store them in the table. Below is my code snippet.

```
private static async void ConfigureAzureStorageTable()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
            CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        TableResult result = new TableResult();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("test");
        table.CreateIfNotExists();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            var verifyVariableEntityObject = new VerifyVariableEntity()
            {
                ConsumerId = String.Format("{0}", i),
                Score = String.Format("{0}", i * 2 + 2),
                PartitionKey = String.Format("{0}", i),
                RowKey = String.Format("{0}", i * 2 + 2)
            };
            TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(verifyVariableEntityObject);
            try
            {
                table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is anything incorrect with the usage of the method?

Comment: If you don't wait for it to finish, it may not finish (especially if your process exits).  And you won't find out about any errors.

Comment: If you don't wait for it to finish, it's probably not going to finish!

Comment: Have you solved this issue, any updates? You could catch the detailed exception within your console application and capture the network package via Fiddler when you inserting records to Azure Table Storage.

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT I decided to go ahead with await ExecuteAsync() option because that way I could insert all records. Without await keyword, some of the records were failing to get inserted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *still* want to `await table.ExecuteAsync()`.  That will mean that `ConfigureAzureStorageTable()` returns control to the caller at that point, which can continue executing.

The way you have it in the question, `ConfigureAzureStorageTable()` is going to continue past the call to `table.ExecuteAsync()` and exit, and things like `table` will go out of scope, while the `table.ExecuteAsync()` task is still not complete.

There are plenty of caveats about using `async void` on SO and elsewhere that you will also need to consider.  You could just as easily have your method as `async Task` but not await it in the caller *yet*, but keep the returned `Task` around for clean termination, etc.

**Edit**: one addition - you almost certainly want to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on your `await` there, as you don't appear to need to preserve any context.  This [blog post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) has some guidelines on that and async in general.

Answer (score 2):

According to your requirement, I have tested your scenario on my side by using `CloudTable.ExecuteAsync` and `CloudTable.ExecuteBatchAsync` successfully. Here is my code snippet about using `CloudTable.ExecuteBatchAsync` to insert records to Azure Table Storage, you could refer to it.

**Program.cs Main**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
            CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        TableResult result = new TableResult();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("test");
        table.CreateIfNotExists();

        //Generate records to be inserted into Azure Table Storage
        var entities = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).Select(i => new VerifyVariableEntity()
        {
            ConsumerId = String.Format("{0}", i),
            Score = String.Format("{0}", i * 2 + 2),
            PartitionKey = String.Format("{0}", i),
            RowKey = String.Format("{0}", i * 2 + 2)
        });

        //Group records by PartitionKey and prepare for executing batch operations
        var batches = TableBatchHelper<VerifyVariableEntity>.GetBatches(entities);

        //Execute batch operations in parallel
        Parallel.ForEach(batches, new ParallelOptions()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5
        }, (batchOperation) =>
        {
            try
            {
                table.ExecuteBatch(batchOperation);
                Console.WriteLine("Writing {0} records", batchOperation.Count);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ExecuteBatch throw a exception:" + ex.Message);
            }
        });
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**TableBatchHelper.cs**

```
public class TableBatchHelper<T> where T : ITableEntity
{
    const int batchMaxSize = 100;

    public static IEnumerable<TableBatchOperation> GetBatches(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var list = new List<TableBatchOperation>();
        var partitionGroups = items.GroupBy(arg => arg.PartitionKey).ToArray();
        foreach (var group in partitionGroups)
        {
            T[] groupList = group.ToArray();
            int offSet = batchMaxSize;
            T[] entities = groupList.Take(offSet).ToArray();
            while (entities.Any())
            {
                var tableBatchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
                foreach (var entity in entities)
                {
                    tableBatchOperation.Add(TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity));
                }
                list.Add(tableBatchOperation);
                entities = groupList.Skip(offSet).Take(batchMaxSize).ToArray();
                offSet += batchMaxSize;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

**Note:** As mentioned in the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables#insert-a-batch-of-entities) about inserting a batch of entities:

> A single batch operation can include up to **100** entities.
>
> All entities in a single batch operation must have **the same partition key**.

In summary, please try to check whether it could work on your side. Also, you could capture the detailed exception within your console application and capture the HTTP request via [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to catch the HTTP error requests when you inserting records to Azure Table Storage.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `TableBatchOperation` to run batches of N inserts at once?

```
private const int BatchSize = 100;

private static async void ConfigureAzureStorageTable()
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
        CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    TableResult result = new TableResult();
    CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("test");
    table.CreateIfNotExists();

    var batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        var verifyVariableEntityObject = new VerifyVariableEntity()
        {
            ConsumerId = String.Format("{0}", i),
            Score = String.Format("{0}", i * 2 + 2),
            PartitionKey = String.Format("{0}", i),
            RowKey = String.Format("{0}", i * 2 + 2)
        };
        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(verifyVariableEntityObject);
        batchOperation.Add(insertOperation);

        if (batchOperation.Count >= BatchSize)
        {
            try
            {
                await table.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation);
                batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    if(batchOperation.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            await table.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

You can adjust BatchSize to what you need. Small disclaimer: I didn't try to run this, though it should work.

But I can't help but wonder why is your function `async void`? That should be reserved for event handlers and similar ones where you cannot decide the interface. In most cases you want to return a task. Because now the caller cannot catch exceptions that occur in this function.

Answer (score 0):

async void is not a good practice unless it is an eventhandler.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

If you plan to insert many records into azure table storage, batch insert is your best bet.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablebatchoperation.aspx

Keep in mind that it has limit of 100 table operations per batch.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by 
forcing ExecuteAsync to wait for the results before it exist..

```
table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```